# Moving Nuxt store to modules mode generates 'getters should be function' error

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Since classic mode is going to be deprecated soon, I'm trying to move my store to modules mode. However I do want to keep state, actions, mutations and getters in separate files. So lets say I currently only have one module - auth. This is my store structure:

```
store
 |_ modules
 |  |_auth
 |    |_actions.js
 |    |_getters.js
 |    |_mutations.js
 |    |_state.js
 |
 |_actions.js
 |_auth.js
 |_getters.js
 |_index.js
 |_mutations.js
 |_state.js
```

`store\modules\auth\state.js` currently has only one property:

```js
export const state = () => {
  return {
    token: null
  }
}
```

This is `store\modules\auth\getters.js`

```js
export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return !!state.token
  }
}
```

Then in my `store\auth.js`:

```js
import {actions} from './modules/auth/actions'
import {getters} from './modules/auth/getters'
import {mutations} from './modules/auth/mutations'
import {state} from './modules/auth/state'

export {
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
  state
}
```

And finally in my `store\index.js` I only have this code:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  strict: true
}
```

This gives me the following error:
`[vuex] getters should be function but "getters.getters" in module "modules.auth" is {}.`

I've been scratching my head for hours now and don't know how to tackle that.

I tried to do something like that, for example:

```
export const getters = () => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token
  }
}
```

That did compile, but in the console it threw another error:
`[vuex] unknown getter: auth/isAuthenticated`

And it also gives me this warning:
`store/modules/auth/state.js should export a method that returns an object`

And there I thought I do that...

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally managed to solve it. Maybe someone will find it helpful.

First of all, my export of getters was wrong. This is the correct way to do it:

```
export default {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return !!state.token
  }
}
```

Same thing about the state:

```
export default () => ({
  token: null
})
```

And then I had to move the `auth` module from `modules` to folder to be under `store` folder. I also removed `index.js` and `auth.js` files.

```
store
 |_auth
 | |_actions.js
 | |_getters.js
 | |_mutations.js
 | |_state.js
 |
 |_actions.js
 |_getters.js
 |_mutations.js
 |_state.js
```

Now everything worked just fine!